# Use of template keyword before dependent template name

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug, dependent-name

Considering the following code example, I would expect to have to use the `template` keyword here to guide the compiler to treat variable `v` as a template. However, MSVC rejects the use of the `template` keyword, whereas Clang and GCC actually require it. Which specific rule in the C++20 standard either mandates or forbids the use of the `template` keyword in this case?

```
struct s {
    template<typename...>
    static constexpr auto v = true;
};
// all ok
static_assert([](auto x){ return decltype(x)::template v<>; }(s{}));
// clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
static_assert([](auto x){ return x.template v<>; }(s{}));
// clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok
static_assert([](auto x){ return x.v<>; }(s{}));
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zxb3Eb4v7)

---

The error message from Clang:

```
<source>:10:36: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'v'
as a dependent template name
   10 | static_assert([](auto x){ return x.v<>; }(s{}));
      |                                    ^
      |                                    template
```

The error message from MSVC:

```
<source>(8): error C2187: syntax error: 'template' was unexpected here
<source>(8): note: see reference to function template instantiation
'auto <lambda_2>::operator ()<s>(_T1) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            _T1=s
        ]
```

Comment: Replacing `(auto x)` with `(s x)` then they all work. 
So the compilers are having trouble deducing auto.

Comment: I would say msvc is wrong.

Comment: @QuentinUK in this context, `auto` makes the lambdas templated. Even though they are called with an `s`, their body must be valid for any type; the compiler must not assume `x` is an `s` (unless for non-observables, as per the as-if rule).

Comment: Even though non-normative, this [example](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#general-example-3) shows that  `.template v<>`is the correct form: `p->X<0>::f(); // error: A​::​X not found in ((p->X) < 0) > ​::​f()`.
I'm trying to understand how [`[basic.lookup.qual.general]/3`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#general-3) is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, `x` and `decltype(x)` are dependent, and `template` is allowed and necessary in all cases. There is an MSVC compiler bug.

#### C++ standard wording

As for dependent types, including `decltype`:

> A type is dependent if it is:
>
> - a template parameter,
> - [...]
> - denoted by `decltype(expression)`, where `expression` is type-dependent.

- [[temp.dep.type] p7.10](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type#7.10)

Furthermore, `x` is type-dependent because (see [[temp.dep.expr] p3.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.expr#3.1)) it is:

> associated by name lookup with one or more declarations declared with a dependent type

The `auto` parameter for the generic lambda makes the call operator a function template, so naturally, `x` is associated with a template parameter, which is dependent.
Therefore `template` is necessary for `decltype(x)::template v<>`. All compilers agree and this is correct.

In the statement

> ```cpp
> return x.template v<>;
> ```

`x` is type-dependent because it is associated by name lookup with an implicit template parameter of the generic lambda's call operator. Therefore, `template` is necessary.

---

*Note: Besides the standardese, it's intuitively necessary because `x.v <` could be interpreted as *"`x.v` is less than ..."* if it isn't known that `v` is a template.
This is formally stated in [[temp.names] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3).*

*See also: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/5740428)*

#### MSVC compiler bug

The fact that MSVC doesn't allow `.template v<>` is obviously a bug. It's worth noting that MSVC does accept:

```cpp
[](s x){ return x.template v<>; }(s{})
```

However, using `auto` instead of `s` as the parameter type leads to a compiler error. This makes no sense at all, since `template` and `typename` are optional and adding them unnecessarily should never cause failure.

---

*Note: I was unable to find an existing bug report in the [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp?q=generic+lambda+dependent+type), so maybe this hasn't been reported yet. You may want to report this bug.*

Comment: I've read as much as I could about dependent lookups but cannot find a quote to support _"Therefore, `template` is necessary"_. I Couldn't even find a quote touching on the subject of `template_name < template_parameter_list > ...` being ambiguous with `( template_name < template_parameter_list ) > ...` .

Comment: @YSC it's in this very answer, although in the note. See https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3. `template` is necessary because none of the bullets are satisfied, so that `<` is interpreted as a less-than operator. The first bullet states that `template` would result in parsing `<` as a delimiter of a template-argument-list, which is exactly what we need. If it was parsed as a less-than operator, the program would be ill-formed.

Comment: Also note that the second bullet does not apply because name lookup doesn't find anything for dependent member lookup. This is all beyond the scope of this answer though, and honestly belongs in [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/5740428)

Comment: I've completely missed this item `/3`, which is kind of scary. Many thanks.

Comment: It seems the bug is rather obvious, I'm not sure how it has slipped through the cracks all these years. I've reported the bug to Microsoft with the help of your investigative work.